# What is the difference between Web deploy and FTP deploy in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, deployment

Recently I need to deploy our website into a QA environment. I find that there are a lot of options in the deployment methods, including FTP and Web Deploy. Before, I often used FTP deployment, which would copy all the website files from Visual Studio to the Server.

But this time, I noticed the Web deploy method. It also requires an account and password to upload the files. But
what is the difference between the two methods?

[image]

Comment: I know this is an old question but in my experience Web Deploy publishes the website a lot faster than FTP, although this may just be my internet connection!

Comment: @bolt19 - It's not just your internet connection, web deploy does not issue a different command for each operation. Instead, it does a comparison at the start of the sync and only transfers changes. See the article I referenced in my answer.

Answer (score 10):

Web deploy offers several benefits over FTP.
Here's the sum up:

> Web Deploy is faster than FTP. Web Deploy is secure. Web Deploy can
>   apply transforms during deployment. Web Deploy integrates with Visual
>   Studio 2010 and WebMatrix. Web Deploy is extensible.

You can read the full comparison details [here](https://www.iis.net/learn/publish/using-web-deploy/introduction-to-web-deploy).

Answer (score 1):

I used both. In my opinion:

Web deploy: take an example, when you have many users on the server, each user has one website, and web deploy is for each user with each website -> I can't deploy my website to another folder of other user's website, because I don't have permission.

FTP: like when you are the administrator of a server, you can deploy directly. With FTP, you can open [Windows Explorer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer), pass the link: fpt://domain.com → <kbd>Enter</kbd> → and then you can copy/paste seem like a local computer without FTP deploy in Visual Studio. But make sure the server can open an FTP connection [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd421710(v=ws.10).aspx).